# Google Chat 経由で登録したタスクが、Tasks API で取得できない

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

## やりたいこと

GoogleAppsScriptにて、スクリプト実行ユーザのToDoリスト内に存在するタスクのうち、
「日付」（due）の値がスクリプト実行日以前のものを取得するプログラムの作成

## 問題点

GASのサービス「Tasks API」を用いて、「GoogleCalendar」「Gmail」の画面から登録したタスクが取得できることを確認した。
しかし、GoogleChatのスペース内にある「タスク」機能を使用して登録したタスクについては、
割り当て先＝スクリプト実行ユーザとして登録した場合でも取得できなかった。（タスクを登録したユーザも同一です）

- 「タスク」機能を使用して、スクリプト実行ユーザに割り当て先を設定して登録
  [image: screenshots001]
- スクリプト実行時点での、スクリプト実行ユーザの「マイタスク」内に存在するタスク一覧
  [image: screenshots002]
- スクリプト実行結果
  [image: screenshots003]

## 質問内容

- この方法で、GoogleChatの「タスク」機能を用いて割り当てたタスクが取得できなかった理由
  （「タスク機能」を使用して登録したタスクは、割り当て先のユーザには紐付かない？）
- GoogleChatの「タスク」機能を用いて割り当てたタスクの、Tasks APIでの正しい取得方法

## 補足

下記の公式ドキュメントには、目を通しております。
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks

以上、他にも情報にアップデートがあれば追記していきます。
何卒、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 既知の問題のようですね。まだ修正されていないようです。https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173343990

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
いただいたリンクに記載されている通りですね、沼にはまる前に確認できて助かりました。
個人的に、Tasks API経由ではない方法を検討してみます。

また、今後はGoogle Cloud Platformの投稿も参考にするようにいたします。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。他の方法で取得ができるようですと、他のユーザの方々にも喜ばれると思います。